# Unable to use custom theme with daisyUI and TailwindCSS in a Typescript project

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, remix.run, daisyui

I am unable to use custom theme for daisyUI with TailwindCSS. I looked for examples but found only JS ones.

I tried:

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
export default {
content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
theme: {
extend: {
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        'devytheme': {
          'primary': '#84cc16',
          'secondary': '#8f4263',
          'accent': '#5c7f67',
          'neutral': '#291e00',
          'base-100': '#e9e7e7',
          'info': '#3abff8',
          'success': '#36d399',
          'warning': '#fbbd23',
          'error': '#f87272',
        },
      }
    ],
    theme: 'devytheme',
  },
},
   },
   plugins: [require("daisyui")],
   } satisfies Config;
```

And some more variation for example this:

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      daisyui: {
        themes: {
          'devytheme': {
            'primary': '#84cc16',
            'secondary': '#8f4263',
            'accent': '#5c7f67',
            'neutral': '#291e00',
            'base-100': '#e9e7e7',
            'info': '#3abff8',
            'success': '#36d399',
            'warning': '#fbbd23',
            'error': '#f87272',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
} satisfies Config;
```

When the code doesn't work I get the following error and no styles are applied to the app.

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

Original `tailwind.config.ts` was as follows:

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

export default {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
} satisfies Config;
```

Any help will be great.
It is a Remix app that was started using Blues Stacks.

Comment: look in this project structure https://stackblitz.com/edit/daisyui-remix/

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING I see a tailwind.config in JS and no custom theme, am I missing something?